# Unhandled IOErrorEvent:. text=Error #2038: File I/O Error

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript, flex4

We are facing issue when we try to upload a file on flex UI on Mozilla browser.

We are using `flash.net.FileReference` object for uploading a file.

**It works fine when we use IE7 or IE8.**

```
Error reported on debug is:
Error #2044: Unhandled IOErrorEvent:. text=Error #2038: File I/O Error.
```

We are new to flex, so we are not in a good position to understand the reason behind this error.

Any helpful answers will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: You may want to invest in Charles Proxy, which lets you look at the traffic going across the wire.  It will often have better information for you.

Answer (score 2):

some code would be helpful, but generally it should be fixed by listening to [`FileReference.IOErrorEvent`](http://help.adobe.com//en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/FileReference.html#event%3aioError) like in this [example](http://help.adobe.com//en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/FileReference.html#includeExamplesSummary)

Comment: I met this issue long ago and www0z0k is right, listening to `IOErrorEvent` is probably what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to my comment. Any `IOErrorEvent` dispatched without listener(s) will throw an IO error -- even if you dispatch it by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

One cause of this can be any failure status code response (4## or 5##) from the requested URL on the upload.